# spring aop not firing for annotation

Tags: spring, aop

I am using an annotation on a method. and whenever that annoation is present I want to intercept it using aop. What am i missing.

```xml
<bean id="emailAdvice" class="com.merc.spring.aop.advice.MultiThreadEmailAdvice"/> 

<aop:config>  
    <aop:aspect ref="emailAdvice">  
        <aop:around 
            method="fork"  
            pointcut="execution(* org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(..))"/>  
    </aop:aspect>  
    <aop:aspect ref="emailAdvice">
        <aop:around method="sendEmailAdvice" pointcut="@annotation(sendMailAnnotation)" arg-names="sendMailAnnotation"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

```java
@SendMailAnnotation()
public void testAnnotationEmail() {
    System.out.println("send an email");
}

@Aspect
public class MultiThreadEmailAdvice {
    public void sendEmailAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, SendMailAnnotation sendMailAnnotation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("before method execution");

        pjp.proceed();

        System.out.println("after method execution");

        System.out.println(sendMailAnnotation.from());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
@annotation(sendMailAnnotation)
```

To

```
@annotation(<package>.SendMailAnnotation).
```

in your bean definition.

Ex

```
<aop:around method="sendEmailAdvice" pointcut="@annotation(com.merc.spring.aop.advice.SendMailAnnotation)" arg-names="sendMailAnnotation"/>
```

Comment: If I do that I get the following error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Comment: `<package>` has to be replaced with your annotations package ex `com.merc.spring.aop.advice`, Updated the answer

Comment: That is exactly what I had <aop:around method="sendEmailAdvice" pointcut="@annotation(com.merc.annotation.mail.SendMailAnnotation)" arg-names="sendMailAnnotation"/>

Comment: Can you share the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the service class that call the annotated method was not spring managed. Once making in spring managed, it worked fine